# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at popup.js:1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery and see that this question has been asked on several occasion but cannot find the answer within the library.

Why do I continue to get the above error message with such a simple script? All I am trying to do is hide the class 'answer' upon opening of the html page

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#faq-panel > div .answer').hide();

  });
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Sign Up Form</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
     <!--   <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" > -->
        <link href="../css/popups.css" rel="stylesheet" >

       <script src="../js/popup.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>







        <header class="page-title">
             <a class="return" href="../"><span>Return</span></a>
            <h1>Pricing</h1>
            <div><h2>SPECIAL LIMITED-TIME OFFER FOR PRESTO BUSINESS SOLUTION PARTNERS</h2></div>
        </header>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="heading">
            <p>We are offering big long-term discounts in 2017 to organisations who are serious about embracing change and want to partner with us to install operational excellence </p>
        </div>




            <form action="/bat/clientsignup.php" method="post">



            <fieldset class="contact clearfix">

                <label for="mail"></label>
            <div class="signup">
                <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_email" placeholder="enter your work e-mail" required>
                <button type="submit">Sign up today & try PRESTO free-of-charge</button>
            </div>
            </fieldset>


            </form>


             <img class="presto-logo" src="../images/vsm.png">


<!--     <div style="opacity: 1;">
        <ul class="subscription-type">
            <li>Yearly SAVE 18%</li>
            <li> | </li>
            <li>Two Yearly SAVE 32%</li>
            <li> | </li>
            <li>Monthly</li>
        </ul>-->


        <div class="packages" style="opacity: 1;">
            <div class="package basic" data-tier="basic">
                <div class="summary">
                <div class="title">Basic</div>
                <div class="price"> <span class="dollar">€</span><span class="currency fw300"></span> <span class="amount">4</span> <span class="per_month">/ Mo</span><span class="vat"> +VAT</span> </div>
                <div class="bottom" style="display: block;">billed annually</div>
                <div class="minimum_users">Minimum 50 users</div>
                <div class="tier_blurb dh">
                <div class="blurb_title"><span>Assess your current state</span></div>
                <div class="description">All the essentials you need to identify where waste opportunities exist and ensure your operational support documentation archive is kept in order</div>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="features">

                <div class="TOPP-support">
                <h5>TOPP TI Support</h5>
                <ul>
                <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>E-mail product support with 24-hour turn-around time</p></li>
                </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="TOPP-support">
                <h5>Functionality</h5>
                <ul>
                <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>Operational readiness</p></li>
                <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>Waste identification</p></li>
                </ul>
                </div>




            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="package standard" data-tier="standard">
                <div class="top with_line">Most popular</div>
                <div class="summary">
                    <div class="title">Standard</div>
                    <div class="price"> <span class="dollar">€</span> <span class="currency fw300"></span> <span class="amount">6</span> <span class="per_month">/ Mo</span><span class="vat"> +VAT</span>  </div>
                    <div class="bottom" style="display: block;">billed annually</div>
                    <div class="minimum_users">Minimum 100 users</div>
                    <div class="tier_blurb dh">
                        <div class="blurb_title"><span>Design target model, assign responsibility & deploy resources</span></div>
                        <div class="description">Engage your team to align business process responsibilities to their respective owners while performing initial cost benefits analysis on the business opportunities available</div>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                <h4 class="basic-plus">Basic plus...</h4>
                <div class="TOPP-support">
                    <h5>TOPP TI Support</h5>
                        <ul>
                            <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>4 hours of video conference consultation with a TOPP TI Lean Six Sigma black belt</p></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="TOPP-support">
                    <h5>Functionality</h5>
                        <ul>
                            <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>Kanban project management</p></li>
                       <!--     <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>Best practice interactive corporate newsfeed</li>         -->
                            <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>IT functional bug & enhancement tracker</p></li>
                            <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>Support documentation historical tracking</li>
                            <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>Opportunity cost/benefits analysis</li>
                            <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>RACI matrix reporting</p></li>
                            <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>Client demand heat map</li>
                        </ul>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="package pro" data-tier="pro">
            <div class="top with_line for_banks">Reccomended to banks</div>
            <div class="summary">
                <div class="title">Pro</div>
                <div class="price"> <span class="dollar">€</span> <span class="currency fw300"></span> <span class="amount">8</span> <span class="per_month">/ Mo</span> <span class="vat"> +VAT</span> </div>
                <div class="bottom" style="display: block;">billed annually</div>
                <div class="minimum_users">Minimum 100 users</div>
                <div class="tier_blurb dh">
                    <div class="blurb_title"><span>Cross-train, optimise performance & benchmark results</span></div>
                    <div class="description">Perform risk & control self assessments, maximise knowledge retention and do away with annual reviews by measuring performance in real time. Use Lean logic to capture cycle times & benchmark progress with robust historical data.</div>
                </div>
            </div>

              <h4 class="standard-plus">Standard plus...</h4>
                <div class="TOPP-support">
                    <h5>TOPP TI Support</h5>
                        <ul>
                            <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>10 hours of video conference consultation with a TOPP TI Lean Six Sigma black belt</p></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="TOPP-support">
                    <h5>Functionality</h5>
                        <ul>
                            <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>Value Stream Mapping with SIPOC UI </p></li>
                            <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>FTE supply / demand workload profile & RACI</p></li>
                            <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>Risk heat map, integrated calendar & reminder scheduling</li>
                            <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>Risk & control self assessment & EASI opportunity analysis</p></li>
                            <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>Process checklist manager</p></li>
                            <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>Process cycle time & benchmarking manager notebook</li>
                            <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>Skills 4-steps to excellence growth manager</li>

                        </ul>
                </div>


            </div>

            <div class="package enterprise" data-tier="enterprise">
            <div class="summary">
            <div class="title">Enterprise</div>
            <div class="price"> <span class="dollar">€</span> <span class="currency fw300"></span> <span class="amount">10</span> <span class="per_month">/ Mo</span> <span class="vat"> +VAT</span> </div>
            <div class="bottom" style="display: block;">billed annually</div>
            <div class="minimum_users">Minimum 150 users</div>
            <div class="tier_blurb dh"> <div class="blurb_title"><span>Install sense of urgency, purpose & best practice awareness</span></div>
                <div class="description">Eliminate silo-specific knowledge gaps and install a corporate-wide best practice culture together with a constant discipline to accelerate decision making and the autonomous elimination of ‘low hanging fruits’.
</div>
            </div>
            </div>

             <h4 class="pro-plus">Pro plus...</h4>

                <div class="TOPP-support">
                    <h5>Functionality</h5>
                        <ul>
                            <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>Interactive corporate newsfeed</li>
                            <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>Talent differentiators analytics for leadership, professional, technical and soft skills</p></li>
                            <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>3-tier risk & compliance impact reporting</li>
                            <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>Client special service cost tracker</p></li>
                            <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>KPI tracking & efficiency assessment streamlining</li>
                            <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>Issue management advanced reporting</li>
                            <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>Go-to-Gemba mobile device SIPOC interaction functionality</p></li>
                            <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>PRESTO sense-of-urgency discipline</p></li>

                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>






    <div class="frequently-asked-questions">
        <br>
        <div class="container">
        <h1>Frequently Asked Questions</h1>

        <ul id="faq-panel">
            <li>
                <div class="question"> How does your pricing work? <img class="caret" src="/images/chevron.png" width="25"> </div>
                <div class="answer"> We’re a tiered subscription service, and our pricing is based on the number of people on your team as well as the plan that’s best for you. Check out our handy calculator above to get a personalized quote pronto. </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="question"> Which plan is right for me? <img class="caret" src="/images/chevron.png" width="25"> </div>
                <div class="answer"> That’s a good question and there are a number of factors to consider. Reach out to our Customer Success Team-—we’ll be happy to help you figure it out. </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="question"> Can I pay monthly? <img class="caret" src="/images/chevron.png" width="25"> </div>
                <div class="answer"> Sure. We offer monthly, yearly, and two-yearly plans. A lot of our customers prefer to go for yearly or two-yearly because they’re the most economical choice—you can save up to 32%. But monthly is totally cool, too. </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="question"> Can I use this for my whole organisation, or just my team? <img class="caret" src="/images/chevron.png" width="25"> </div>
                <div class="answer"> Either or both! That’s the beauty of dapulse—we have huge enterprises using it organization-wide as well as one and two-people teams. You’re a small team working inside a huge corporation, you say? That’s good, too. Plenty of our customers use dapulse to improve the way their own team or department operates. </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="question"> Do you offer discounts? <img class="caret" src="/images/chevron.png" width="25"> </div>
                <div class="answer"> We’re happy to offer discounted pricing to nonprofits and NGOs. Or if you can beat us in Street Fighter 2. (But we’re realllllly good… just saying.) Contact our Customer Success Team for more info. </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="question"> Can I change my plan? <img class="caret" src="/images/chevron.png" width="25"> </div>
                <div class="answer"> Totes. You can upgrade, downgrade, or cancel your plan any time you want. </div>
            </li>
            <li class="faq">
                <div class="question"> What type of product support is available? <img class="caret" src="/images/chevron.png" width="25"> </div>
                <div class="answer"> The trial is free, but after that, yeah, you’ll need to subscribe to one of our plans to continue using dapulse. Don’t give us that look ;) We’re committed to building an amazing product that provides real and tangible value to you every day. At 16 cents per user a day, our Basic plan sets you back less than a pencil per person. There’s no greater investment than pulling your team together and finding a great way to get work done, and many of our customers tell us that their experience with dapulse is truly invaluable. Imagine never missing another deadline, totally eliminating angry phone calls from clients, or putting an end to painful email threads—for real. Imagine actually enjoying your everyday life at work. Priceless, no? </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="question"> Who should be the primary users? <img class="caret" src="/images/chevron.png" width="25"> </div>
                <div class="answer"> We accept all major credit cards. Some of our developers could probably be bribed with cookies, but you didn’t hear that from us. </div>
            </li>
        </ul>

        </div>
    </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$()` isn't a part of standard JavaScript, it's jQuery, a custom library that has to be added to your page before you can use it. The other questions all mention jQuery, the answers stress that it has to be included *before* it's used, and it's even _in your tags_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add jQuery library before you use it, try to add the follow reference to the head section.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note that jQuery is frequently updated with new versions that fix bugs and security issues. Always check the latest version of jQuery on the jQuery website, don't copy/paste the URL in this answer blindly.

Answer (score 2):

**Just need to add JQuery**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#faq-panel > div .answer').hide();

});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Sign Up Form</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--   <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" > -->
  <link href="../css/popups.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/popup.js"></script>
  
</head>

<body>
  <header class="page-title">
    <a class="return" href="../"><span>Return</span></a>
    <h1>Pricing</h1>
    <div>
      <h2>SPECIAL LIMITED-TIME OFFER FOR PRESTO BUSINESS SOLUTION PARTNERS</h2>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="heading">
      <p>We are offering big long-term discounts in 2017 to organisations who are serious about embracing change and want to partner with us to install operational excellence</p>
    </div>

    <form action="/bat/clientsignup.php" method="post">
      <fieldset class="contact clearfix">

        <label for="mail"></label>
        <div class="signup">
          <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_email" placeholder="enter your work e-mail" required>
          <button type="submit">Sign up today & try PRESTO free-of-charge</button>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <img class="presto-logo" src="../images/vsm.png">

    <div class="packages" style="opacity: 1;">
      <div class="package basic" data-tier="basic">
        <div class="summary">
          <div class="title">Basic</div>
          <div class="price"> <span class="dollar">€</span><span class="currency fw300"></span>  <span class="amount">4</span>  <span class="per_month">/ Mo</span><span class="vat"> +VAT</span> 
          </div>
          <div class="bottom" style="display: block;">billed annually</div>
          <div class="minimum_users">Minimum 50 users</div>
          <div class="tier_blurb dh">
            <div class="blurb_title"><span>Assess your current state</span>
            </div>
            <div class="description">All the essentials you need to identify where waste opportunities exist and ensure your operational support documentation archive is kept in order</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="features">

          <div class="TOPP-support">
            <h5>TOPP TI Support</h5>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
                <p>E-mail product support with 24-hour turn-around time</p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div class="TOPP-support">
            <h5>Functionality</h5>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
                <p>Operational readiness</p>
              </li>
              <li>
                <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
                <p>Waste identification</p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="package standard" data-tier="standard">
        <div class="top with_line">Most popular</div>
        <div class="summary">
          <div class="title">Standard</div>
    s="bottom" style="display: block;">billed annually</div>
          <div class="minimum_users">Minimum 100 users</div>
          <div class="tier_blurb dh">
            <div class="blurb_title"><span>Design target model, assign responsibility & deploy resources</span>
            </div>
            <div class="description">Engage your team to align business process responsibilities to their respective owners while performing initial cost benefits analysis on the business opportunities available</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <h4 class="basic-plus">Basic plus...</h4>
        <div class="TOPP-support">
          <h5>TOPP TI Support</h5>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
              <p>4 hours of video conference consultation with a TOPP TI Lean Six Sigma black belt</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="TOPP-support">
          <h5>Functionality</h5>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
              <p>Kanban project management</p>
            </li>
            <!--     <li><img class="check" src="../images/check.png"><p>Best practice interactive corporate newsfeed</li>         -->
            <li>
              <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
              <p>IT functional bug & enhancement tracker</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
              <p>Support documentation historical tracking</li>
            <li>
              <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
              <p>Opportunity cost/benefits analysis</li>
            <li>
              <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
              <p>RACI matrix reporting</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
              <p>Client demand heat map</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="package pro" data-tier="pro">
        <div class="top with_line for_banks">Reccomended to banks</div>
        <div class="summary">
          <div class="title">Pro</div>
          <div class="price"> <span class="dollar">€</span>  <span class="currency fw300"></span>  <span class="amount">8</span>  <span class="per_month">/ Mo</span>  <span class="vat"> +VAT</span> 
          </div>
          <div class="bottom" style="display: block;">billed annually</div>
          <div class="minimum_users">Minimum 100 users</div>
          <div class="tier_blurb dh">
            <div class="blurb_title"><span>Cross-train, optimise performance & benchmark results</span>
            </div>
            <div class="description">Perform risk & control self assessments, maximise knowledge retention and do away with annual reviews by measuring performance in real time. Use Lean logic to capture cycle times & benchmark progress with robust historical data.</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <h4 class="standard-plus">Standard plus...</h4>
        <div class="TOPP-support">
          <h5>TOPP TI Support</h5>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
              <p>10 hours of video conference consultation with a TOPP TI Lean Six Sigma black belt</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="TOPP-support">
          <h5>Functionality</h5>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
              <p>Value Stream Mapping with SIPOC UI</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
              <p>FTE supply / demand workload profile & RACI</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
              <p>Risk heat map, integrated calendar & reminder scheduling</li>
            <li>
              <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
              <p>Risk & control self assessment & EASI opportunity analysis</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
              <p>Process checklist manager</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
              <p>Process cycle time & benchmarking manager notebook</li>
            <li>
              <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
              <p>Skills 4-steps to excellence growth manager</li>

          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
 <div class="package enterprise" data-tier="enterprise">
        <div class="summary">
          <div class="title">Enterprise</div>
          <div class="price"> <span class="dollar">€</span>  <span class="currency fw300"></span>  <span class="amount">10</span>  <span class="per_month">/ Mo</span>  <span class="vat"> +VAT</span> 
          </div>
          <div class="bottom" style="display: block;">billed annually</div>
          <div class="minimum_users">Minimum 150 users</div>
        <div class="tier_blurb dh">
            <div class="blurb_title"><span>Install sense of urgency, purpose & best practice awareness</span>
            </div>
            <div class="description">Eliminate silo-specific knowledge gaps and install a corporate-wide best practice culture together with a constant discipline to accelerate decision making and the autonomous elimination of ‘low hanging fruits’.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <h4 class="pro-plus">Pro plus...</h4>

        <div class="TOPP-support">
          <h5>Functionality</h5>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
              <p>Interactive corporate newsfeed</li>
            <li>
              <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
              <p>Talent differentiators analytics for leadership, professional, technical and soft skills</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
              <p>3-tier risk & compliance impact reporting</li>
            <li>
              <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
              <p>Client special service cost tracker</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
              <p>KPI tracking & efficiency assessment streamlining</li>
            <li>
              <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
              <p>Issue management advanced reporting</li>
            <li>
              <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
              <p>Go-to-Gemba mobile device SIPOC interaction functionality</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img class="check" src="../images/check.png">
              <p>PRESTO sense-of-urgency discipline</p>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="frequently-asked-questions">
    <br>
    <div class="container">
      <h1Frequently Asked Questions</h1>

      <ul id="faq-panel">
        <li>
          <div class="question">How does your pricing work?
            <img class="caret" src="/images/chevron.png" width="25">
          </div>
          <div class="answer">We’re a tiered subscription service, and our pricing is based on the number of people on your team as well as the plan that’s best for you. Check out our handy calculator above to get a personalized quote pronto.</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="question">Which plan is right for me?
            <img class="caret" src="/images/chevron.png" width="25">
          </div>
          <div class="answer">That’s a good question and there are a number of factors to consider. Reach out to our Customer Success Team-—we’ll be happy to help you figure it out.</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="question">Can I pay monthly?
            <img class="caret" src="/images/chevron.png" width="25">
          </div>
          <div class="answer">Sure. We offer monthly, yearly, and two-yearly plans. A lot of our customers prefer to go for yearly or two-yearly because they’re the most economical choice—you can save up to 32%. But monthly is totally cool, too.</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="question">Can I use this for my whole organisation, or just my team?
            <img class="caret" src="/images/chevron.png" width="25">
          </div>
          <div class="answer">Either or both! That’s the beauty of dapulse—we have huge enterprises using it organization-wide as well as one and two-people teams. You’re a small team working inside a huge corporation, you say? That’s good, too. Plenty of our customers use
            dapulse to improve the way their own team or department operates.</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="question">Do you offer discounts?
            <img class="caret" src="/images/chevron.png" width="25">
          </div>
          <div class="answer">We’re happy to offer discounted pricing to nonprofits and NGOs. Or if you can beat us in Street Fighter 2. (But we’re realllllly good… just saying.) Contact our Customer Success Team for more info.</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="question">Can I change my plan?
            <img class="caret" src="/images/chevron.png" width="25">
          </div>
          <div class="answer">Totes. You can upgrade, downgrade, or cancel your plan any time you want.</div>
        </li>
        <li class="faq">
          <div class="question">What type of product support is available?
            <img class="caret" src="/images/chevron.png" width="25">
          </div>
          <div class="answer">The trial is free, but after that, yeah, you’ll need to subscribe to one of our plans to continue using dapulse. Don’t give us that look ;) We’re committed to building an amazing product that provides real and tangible value to you every day.
            At 16 cents per user a day, our Basic plan sets you back less than a pencil per person. There’s no greater investment than pulling your team together and finding a great way to get work done, and many of our customers tell us that their experience
            with dapulse is truly invaluable. Imagine never missing another deadline, totally eliminating angry phone calls from clients, or putting an end to painful email threads—for real. Imagine actually enjoying your everyday life at work. Priceless,
            no?
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="question">Who should be the primary users?
            <img class="caret" src="/images/chevron.png" width="25">
          </div>
          <div class="answer">We accept all major credit cards. Some of our developers could probably be bribed with cookies, but you didn’t hear that from us.</div>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it should be placed inside `<head>` or before `</body>`

Comment: @kosmos Sorry Code Snippet by default added it to top of my HTML.